# How to get in contact to discuss API calls?

Tags: facebook, api, contacts

We're running a serious Facebook App that gets more and more traction. However, we are now facing API limits... How can I contact Facebook to discuss this? It seems impossible to find any contact information regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is this [contact form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=206103619499608) which is also mentioned in the [Platform Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) of Facebook.

> If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please [contact us](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=206103619499608) as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).